# SQL Server Agent Not Starting

Tags: sql-server

After I reset the admin account password the SQL Agent is not working, it shows "Agent XPs Disabled", so I tried reconfigured it:

```
USE master 
SP_CONFIGURE 'SHOW ADVANCE',1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
SP_CONFIGURE 'AGENT XPs',1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

The service still fails to start and there is no error captured in the ERROR log, I ran another command:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\SQLAGENT.exe -i MSSQLSERVER -c -v
```

The result:

```
Unable to rename D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MS
SQL\Log\ERRORLOG to D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.1 (reason: The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
2021-09-02 13:55:19 - ! [241] Startup error: Unable to initialize error reporting system (reason: 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
2021-09-02 13:55:19 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

Anything else I need to check? Version MSSQL 2008.
Thank you.

Comment: Which edition, Express, Standard, Enterprise? Is the Agent service enabled with Automatic start

Comment: Enterprise. Ya, it's set to auto-start. I also tried to change "Logon AS" to LocalSytem, LocalNetwork... also no luck.

Comment: `MSSQL10_50` This is 2008r2, not 2008. Do you have multiple instances installed? Or perhaps "parts" of multiple instances?

Comment: Oh ya, it is r2. Only have 1 instance.